# Algorithm to count the number of 9s between 1000 and 2000

Tags: algorithm

Can anyone please let me the efficient algorithm to count the number of 9s present between 1000 and 2000.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any pseudo-code that you've come up with on your own that others can comment on?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried, or at least what you think about trying. We 're not going to do your homework.

Comment: Is this homework? You should tag it as such if that's the case

Comment: What does 909 count as - one or two nines?

Comment: Since you didn't mention a programming language you want this to be done in, I'm assuming it's not really programming related.

Comment: @tylermwashburn What a scary comment!  Algorithms can usually be expressed in a language-agnostic manner and are certainly related to programming.

Answer (score 14):

Since it's a fixed number you could precalculate it and hard code it.

There should be 300 nines in that interval.
There is 100*1 nines as the first digit (1009, 1019, ...)
There is 10*10 nines as second digit (1090, 1091, ..., 1190, 1191, ...)
There is 1*100 nines as third digit (1900, 1901, ...)

I can add that 1999 counts as 3 nines for me.

Comment: Given the amount of information provided by the OP, this answer is phenomenal! =)

Answer (score -2):

A simple way to do this in JavaScript (since you didn't mention a language) would be

```
var x = 0,
    i = 1000;
for (; i < 2000; i++) if (/9/.test(i.toString()))
    x++;
```

When the loop finishes, x would be the amount of numbers between 1000 and 2000 with the number 9 in them.

Comment: totally off dude... that would approximate (but even then not be accurate) to the number of **multiples** of 9

Comment: That is wrong, you're not counting the number of nines.

Comment: Isn't this only the count of numbers ending with 9?

Comment: ..Is that not what he's asking?

Comment: @Yuck, absolutely not. @tyler, where do you see in the question the word "multiples"?

Comment: @Yuck: No, it's multiples of 9 (though not quite, as davin points out). For numbers ending in 9, the interval would be 10, not 9.

Comment: @davin He doesn't say it, I just thought that's what he meant.

Comment: @tyler - Sounds like he wants pattern matching in a sense; any number that has the digit 9 anywhere (e.g. 1097, 1939, ...)

Comment: @tyler: Presumably the number of times the digit 9 appears in the numbers from 1000 to 2000. A more literal interpretation would be, the number of times the number 9 appears between 1000 and 2000, but that'd rather trivially be 0.

Comment: @sepp2k So like 1009, 1019, 1029, etc.?

Comment: @tyler: The way I understood it, yes. And then 1090, 1091, ... , 1099 (the latter of which I think should count twice, as there's two nines there, but the OP's question isn't nearly specific enough to know for a fact what he wants).

Comment: @sepp2k I fixed my answer. It doesn't count numbers with doubles like 1099 but it does count the number of numbers with nine in them.

Comment: @tyler, no it wouldn't, the number of multiples of 9 from 1 to 15 is not `(15-1)/9`

Comment: Your solution is still wrong, it counts the number of numbers that contain nine, which also isn't the OP's questions. He wants the number of appearances of the digit 9.

Comment: And if you use `floor`, then the number of mutiples of 9 from 8 to 11 should be `floor((11-8)/9)` which is 0, although there is really 1. Like I said, it's wrong.